# Access a Class method from another particular class

Tags: java, access-modifiers

Class `A`, Class `B`, Class `C` are in the same package.

`A` has `methodA1` and I would like to access it from only class `B` but not Class `C` (user is not supposed to access `methodA1` from `C`). How can I implement something like this in Java?

Comment: make it a (static) inner class?

Answer (score 1):

Classes in the same package are supposed to cooperate with each other. If C is not supposed to have the same level access to A that B has, C should not be in the same package with A and B. So your first option is to move C to a different package.

One possible alternative is making B a nested class within A. As a nested class, it can access private members in A, which C cannot access.

Comment: What do you mean by inheritance option @TimHunter?

Comment: Sorry, was talking about the nested class option. Was thinking in terms of Class B extending Class A and making the method protected instead of the nesting option. Had a brain fart and confused the two for a moment.